# Why do predators reward their enemies?

Tags: predator-series

In the second Predator movie the Elder Predator gave Lieutenant Mike Harrigan a pistol dating back to 1715. In Alien versus Predator the Elder Predator gave Lex, the last survivor of the Antarctica incident, a spear. In the 2018 Predator movie The Fugitive wanted to give Humanity a prototype weapon.

It doesn't make sense because when somebody kills a predator I always thought that others would appear and they would attack you but instead they reward you.

Answer (score 46):

This question shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the Predators' culture. They aren't mindless killing machines; they're hunters with a strict sense of honour. They don't view the humans they hunt as "enemies", but as worthy opponents to test their skills against.

> when somebody kills a predator I always thought that others would appear and they would attack you

That wouldn't be honourable. If a Predator takes on a human and the human wins, that means they've earned their survival. And in the first two cases (*Predator 2* and *Alien vs Predator*), it means they've earned the right to a trophy. It's the Predator's way of honouring their skills.

In the case of the Fugitive, meanwhile, the fact that it wants to give the prototype weapon to humanity is the reason it's a fugitive in the first place: the other Predators disapprove of it giving away such powerful tech, and the Ultimate Predator is dispatched to kill it and retrieve the weapon.

Comment: I remember stumbling on a comment about the first movie, mentioning the Predator removed his suit to have a "fair fight" against Dutch because he was a worthy opponent, unlike the other soldiers he simply killed right away.

Comment: @Clockwork Indeed. There are other occasions where a Predator simply walks straight past people (such as a naked Casey in *The Predator*) because it doesn't see them as threats, let alone worthy hunts.

Comment: Also the trophies act as a method for future predators to recognize worthy opponents.

Comment: The same as a boxing match or MMA fight where frequently the fighters shake hands or even hug after a match.

Comment: @F1Krazy likewise in Predator 2, the female cop is spared because the Predator notices she's pregnant and killing her in that state would be Wrong by its standards of honor.

Comment: This is also why the Predator leaves Weyland alone once its HUD shows it Weyland's cancer (until he attacks it, which is his own fault).

Comment: i believe it was first film that explained this, or it was implied. like the predator sparing the unarmed woman.